# How can my own Maven plugin get the available versions of a Maven artifact?

Tags: java, maven, version, metadata, maven-plugin

I am writing a plugin for Maven, and need be able to determine which versions are available for any given Maven artifact. The maven-metadata.xml file contains this information, but I can't find out how access it from within my plugin.

I tried using `myArtifact.getAvailableVersions()` but it only returns `null`. How can I make this work?

Comment: Why are you trying to implement a plugin on your own? What is the purpose of determining which versions are available?

Comment: Given a maven artifact, I want to be able to find all other minor versions of it in runtime. This will be necessary later on in the plugin (which does more things than what I have stated here). Do you know of any way that this can be achieved?

Comment: find all minor versions in runtime you mean during the runtime of your plugin...The question is what you like to achieve with this information?

Comment: Yes, I meant the runtime of our plugin. I am unable to disclose the purpose of the plugin, but it must include the functionality described here.

Answer (score 1):

*All available versions* could mean different things:

- If you are looking for all available versions of an artifact that has been published on [Maven central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/), you can use their [search api](https://search.maven.org/#api) to get the versions. The REST call `https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:"org.apache.tamaya"+AND+a:"tamaya-core"&core=gav&rows=20&wt=json` will return a json document containing all available versions of the [tamaya-core](https://tamaya.incubator.apache.org/documentation/core.html) artifact. Replace the group id and artifact id of tamaya-core with the data of your artifact and you will get the requested data.
- If the requested artifact is only available in a private repository of your organization, check the documentation of your repository if there is a similar REST api available. For example if you use Sonatype Nexus the REST api is described [here](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-SearchComponents).
- In the unlikely case that the artifact is only available in your local Maven repository on your computer (which would mean that it never has been deployed) you could check directly the file system.